# How can I specify abiFilters within CodeNameOne project?

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-ndk, codenameone

How can I specify abiFilters within CodeNameOne project (Configurations of native libraries that Gradle should build and package with the android APK)?

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject various things to the gradle build as part of the build process using the various build hints but in this case you just shouldn't...

The "right way" is to create a self contained AAR file which includes the library you need and then just drop it into the `android/native` directory. Once it's there your native interface can import the library's Java packages and invoke it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
My native code is already in aar file that supports only armeabi-v7a  (for some reasons). Even that my code is wrapped in aar file, the app failed to load the armeabi-v7a library because the app has not been notified that somme aar supports only armeabi-v7a wich is 32 bit and the created process (default) by the app in device is 64 bit. Is these there any workaround solution to define abiFilters ?

Comment: You can add the build hint `android.xgradle_default_config=ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'; }`

Comment: Thank you .. this build hint works for me .. android.xgradle_default_config=ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'; }